# Quadrilateral $ABCD$ with $AB=AD$, $\angle BAD=60^\circ$, $\angle BCD=120^\circ$. Prove $BC+DC=AC$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, quadrilateral

> In a given quadrilateral $ABCD$, we have
> $$AB = AD, \angle BAD = 60^\circ, \angle BCD = 120^\circ$$
> Prove that $$ BC + DC = AC$$

I know the quadrilateral is cyclic. I have been able to solve this for the special case where $C$ is the midpoint of arc $BD$, but I am not sure how to generalize.

Comment: You should show your proof for the special case. Someone may be able to see a way forward without wasting time duplicating your effort. Plus, showing your work lets readers know what tools and techniques you are comfortable using, which can help answerers avoid explaining things you already know or using approaches beyond your skill level.

Comment: $\triangle ABD$ is equilateral (isosceles with vertex angle of 60 degrees)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $ABD$ is an equilateral triangle.

**Hint:** $ABCD$ is a cyclic quad.

> The result follows by applying Ptolemy's theorem.

Comment: Absolutely sir 

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Continue with the cyclic ABCD, as well as the equilateral triangle ABD.

Locate the point E on AC such that CD = CE. Since $\angle$ACD = $\angle$ABD = 60, CDE is equilateral and CD = DE. Along with AD = BD and $\angle$CAD = $\angle$CBD, we have congruent triangles ADE and BDC. Thus, AE = BC and

$$AC = AE + EC = BC + CD$$.